How to obtain table anchor position relative to world anchor in RealityKit
I'm creating a surface anchor for a table like this
let tableAnchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: .table, minimumBounds: [0.3,0.3]),trackingMode: .continuous)

and a world anchor like this:
let column0: SIMD4<Float> = [1, 0, 0, 0]
let column1: SIMD4<Float> = [0, 1, 0, 0]
let column2: SIMD4<Float> = [0, 0, 1, 0]
let column3: SIMD4<Float> = [0, 0, 0, 1]
                    
let worldAnchor = AnchorEntity(.world(transform: simd_float4x4(columns: (column0,                                                                                 column1, column2, column3))), trackingMode: .continuous)

When the table surface is found I would like to read the tableAnchor position relative to the worldAnchor. I've tried the following. But it doesn't seem to work as I would expect it to.
let event = self.content!.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.AnchoredStateChanged.self, on: tableAnchor, { ce in
  print("Anchor changed", ce.anchor.transform)
  let tableWorldPos = tableAnchor.convert(position:tableAnchor.position, to: worldAnchor)
  print("World pos", tableWorldPos)
})

I've done heaps of AR development over the past years but I'm also quite new to developing inside the Apple eco-system. Any pointers are highly appreciated.
